# Problema en doble consulta de datos de sum en un select en mysql

Tags: mysql

Cuando realizo la consulta me trae un dato mal al que tengo en la base de datos aqui mi consulta:

```
use envase;
select M.inicial, sum(E.cantidad) as cantidad, sum(S.cantidad) as cantidad
from materia M 
right join inventariompe E ON M.id_mat = E.id_mat_inv 
right join inventariomps S ON M.id_mat = S.id_mat_inv2 where M.id_mat = 7;
```

Me trae este resultado:
[image: result]
Los datos de mis dos tablas donde realizo el sum son estas:
[image: entrada]
[image: salida]

Answer (score 0):

Es por que el right join multiplica toda tu consulta ....  puedes darte cuenta cuales son los valores que se van a sumar si quitas las funciones sum, recomiendo que uses subconsultas

Comment: Si eso parece, Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

en este caso al hacer sum como en otros DBMS tienes que colocar un group by, de esta forma:

```
use envase;
select M.inicial, sum(E.cantidad) as cantidad, sum(S.cantidad) as cantidad
from materia M 
right join inventariompe E ON M.id_mat = E.id_mat_inv 
right join inventariomps S ON M.id_mat = S.id_mat_inv2 where M.id_mat = 7
group by M.inicial;
```